# Spoilers cannot be made visible on iPad

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I like to browse this site with my iPad and I noticed that there's no way to make spoilers visible. On your normal browser, the spoilers become visible on mouse-over, but such a thing doesn't really exist on a multitouch device. Maybe adding the same behavior on `click` would resolve the issue (eg. toggle spoiler visibility on click)?

Comment: It's considered fixed for mobile devices: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen -- the iPad is not considered one though

Comment: You can still click on the mobile link though in the footer.

Comment: It works on iPhone (tap on the spoiler and it shows up) so it isn't an iOS issue.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yes, it seems that it's an iPad only problem. I could use the "mobile" version of the site, although the regular one seems better suited for a device like the iPad.

Comment: they did something like this for comment voting/flagging buttons - you tap the area and the buttons appear.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to switch to the mobile version of the site.

As others noted, iPad is not considered a mobile device, just a regular desktop type browser device.